# Manifest error while implementing MaterialNavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-manifest, navigation-drawer

I am trying to integrate [this Material Drawer](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer) to my project, however i am facing a `Manifest` error. I have tried changing the `minSdk` and `targetSdk` as it is suggested on some similar questions but with no success.

Here is the error i get:

```
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Error: [project_path\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\it.neokree\MaterialNavigationDrawer\1.2.9\AndroidManifest.xml:8] Invalid instruction 'overrideLibrary', valid instructions are : REMOVE,REPLACE,STRICT
```

Here is my app manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.package.name">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawer" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**I am using `Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.0`.
What is causing this error?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error by going to the `MaterialDrawer` library `Manifest` and removing the `uses-sdk`:

```
   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"
        tools:overrideLibrary="at.markushi.ui" >
    </uses-sdk>
```

I am not sure if that will bring up any error later on but at least it solve the problem i had